# How long do Caltrops last?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

If Caltrops are activated their effect last for 6 seconds, matching the skill description. But the skill description doesn't mention how long can the trap remain non-activated on the ground, and whether there's anything else which can make Caltrops disappear. What are those details?

Comment: I wonder if the tag could just be demon-hunter.  Seems like it qualifies in a similar way to Zerg or Protoss.

Comment: @bwarner It fits for demon-hunter slightly, but then when you make "monk" and "barbarian", which can refer to completely different paradigms entirely, nevermind just different expressions of the same concept, then it gets messy. To introduce consistency, it is smoother to add the prefix in all cases.

Comment: @Grace Fair enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Caltrops remain on the ground for **30 seconds** if they are not activated.

Also, only five caltrops can be active at a time—laying a sixth caltrop makes the oldest one disappear.

In addition, zone transitions (e.g., entering a dungeon or descending a dungeon floor) immediately remove all caltrops from the previous zone.

Comment: They are removed EVEN if your party, but not you, still in that floor?

Comment: @Michel I do not know; I'll test it when I have the chance and update this answer accordingly.

Comment: @Oak any news on this ?

Comment: Presumably `Custom Engineering` would increase this to 60 seconds.